# Can I stick a text to an input HTML element

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to position two HTML elements with the CSS attribute `float: right;`, an input element next to it the metric unit of the input. So far I've tried placing the unit next to input without placing it in an element, also placing it in a p element, and both input and the element inside a div element; didn't work. I'd like to ask whether there's a way to stick an element next to another?

here's the code:

```css
.caloriesinput {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>Calories</h5>
  <div class="caloriesinput"><input type="text">
    <p>kcal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's how the code shows:

[image]

much appreciated for your time.

Comment: Try span instead of p?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change the display of `p` tag so add this line of code to your CSS:

```
.caloriesinput p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.caloriesinput {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>Calories</h5>
  <div class="caloriesinput"><input type="text"<p>kcal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```